# Disabling find() cache in Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine, integration-testing

I'm using Doctrine inside Symfony and Here is what I do in a **test method:**

```
public function it_should_publish_video()
{
    // fixture setup
    $entityManager = static::bootKernel()->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();

       // video builder constructs a new video (new Video('title','date')) but doesn't persist it.
    $video = VideoBuilder::new()->make();
    $entityManager->persist($video);
    $entityManager->flush();
    $videoService = new VideoService($entityManager);

    // excerice
    $videoService->publish($video->getId());

    // verification
    $publishedVideo = $entityManager->find($video->getId());
    $this->assertEquals($publishedVideo->getStatus(), 'published');
}
```

and here is my **production code:**

```
public function publish($videoId)
{
    $video = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Video::class)->find($videoId);

    // changes the status
    $video->publish();

    // but I don't persist and flush it
}
```

I'm wondering why my test gets passed while I'm not persisting changes.

I think the **find()** is caching the result. I've searched a lot, there are suggestions about using **clear()** before **find()** or using **refresh()** after **find()** or using **findBy()** instead of **find()**. I don't want to change my production code for the sake of testing.
I've read the documentation but I couldn't find a place to disable this kind of cache.

Comment: AFAIK, The only way is to clear the em tracked entities with a ->clear()

Comment: The `find`-method on the EntityManager will keep the entry in the IdentityMap and "restore" it from memory on next find. This is intended behavior and can be used in production setups to reduce unnecessary db calls. The EntityRepository does not have this behavior, so you could switch to that instead (in your test, as you already use it in your actual code).